# ASP.NET CodeFileBaseClass attribute vs. inherit from System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, base-class

I've just created a base class for my pages by inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Page`:

```
public abstract class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ...
}
```

When I noticed that you can also declare a base page in an ASP.NET view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFileBaseClass="PageBase.cs" CodeFile="page.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="page" %>
```

Can someone explain what the pros and cons of either method are? When would you use one over the other, or are they both the same? What happens if you used both at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CodeFileBaseClass`, `CodeFile`, `Inherits` work together with inheritance, not in place of inheritance.

For example, specifying `CodeFile="page.aspx.cs"` without `page.aspx.cs` existing will result in:

```
Parser Error Message: The file '/page.aspx.cs' does not exist.
```

Assuming `page.aspx.cs` exists, specifying `CodeFileBaseClass="PageBase.cs"` without `PageBase.cs` existing will result in:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'PageBase.cs'.
```

On the other hand you may inherit from `PageBase` **without** specifying the `CodeFileBaseClass` attribute. This however could result in possible unexpected behaviour when referencing controls on the page from the base class.

To quote from [Microsoft's @Page MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx):

> ***CodeFileBaseClass***
>   *Specifies the type name of a base class for a page and its associated code-behind class. This attribute is optional, but when it is used the
>   **CodeFile** attribute must also be present. Use this attribute when you want to implement a shared scenario, where you define common
>   fields (and optionally, associated events) in a base class to
>   reference the controls declared in a Web page. Because of the ASP.NET
>   code generation model, if you defined the fields in a base class
>   without using this attribute, at compile time new member definitions
>   would be generated for the controls declared in the Web page (within a
>   separate partial class stub), and your desired scenario would not
>   work. But if you use the **CodeFileBaseClass** attribute to associate
>   the base class with the page, and you make your partial class (its
>   name is assigned to the **Inherits** attribute and its source file is
>   referenced by the **CodeFile** attribute) inherit from the base class,
>   then the fields in the base class will be able to reference the
>   controls on the page after code generation.*

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that, to be on the safe side, always use the `CodeFileBaseClass` attribute and inherit from the base class?

Comment: It seems, that if you intend to share fields in your base class which reference the controls on the page and you do not specify the required page attributes, the integrity of those references is unreliable due to the ASP NET code generation process as described in the quoted text.

Comment: Sorry, to answer you question. I would only code what is needed. If I understood the MSDN help correctly, it seems only if you are sharing fields in your base class which are referencing controls on the page should you also specify the required page attributes to prevent undesirable results. If however you only share fields which do **not** reference controls on the page, then their would be no need to assign the page attributes.